# Way to compare range of commits in pull request on Github?

Tags: github

Scenario, first 5 commits in a PR have already been code reviewed. Made a few more commits and want to focus in on those.

How can I compare a range of commits in the pull request on Github?

Comment: Have you tried making a throwaway branch after the first 5 commits?  make it and push it to github, then you should be able to compare your latest to that branch using the compare button.

Comment: I was hoping for something much quicker and by just using arguments in the URL.

Comment: If you are going to downvote questions you should post a reason.

Comment: Whoever down voted this should explain why.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The most convenient way I found is:

1. Open PR conversation
2. Find the last commit that have already been reviewed and click its hash link, your URL will look like https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/pull/188/commits/2b6c524e6984f300f6c6e08e57c8dbab9497e798
3. Change `commits` to `files` and add `..HEAD` to the end of URL such as https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/pull/188/files/2b6c524e6984f300f6c6e08e57c8dbab9497e798..HEAD

You'll see commits range you want to review in context of the PR.

P.S. Now GitHub provides functionality to view "Changes since your previous code review" but sometimes it is useful to select changes manually

Comment: Couldn't figure out how to use the shift click option provided by GitHub, so this is very helpful.

Comment: You can add this as a search engine in Chrome by right-clicking the address bar, choosing "Edit Search Engines," and clicking "Add." Then use this for the URL: `javascript:location.href = location.href + '/files/%s..HEAD';`

With a keyword of "review-since," for example, this lets you type "review-since<tab>" into the address bar from any PR and paste the SHA in to get to a review since that commit.

Answer (score 42):

Github has added a way to manually select any range of commits in a pull request. See the screenshot:

[image: range of commits feature]

If you need to scroll down to choose more than the viewable commits - it won't work. You can change the css hight of the element

[image]

Comment: As an added note: This feature will link to a URL like:

`https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/pull/<PR>/files/<first commit hash>..<last commit hash>`, like the URL in the accepted answer.

Comment: How do you get this screen? Is this on GitHub?

Comment: ugh, this isn't supported in my version of Github enterprise

Comment: Unfortunately Google Chrome today (for me anyway) has started mapping the Shift key to "open new window" making this solution impossible, and the chrome key mapping is unchangeable

Comment: @BenDelaney, thanks to your observation, I figured that we can manually set the <first commit hash> and <second commit hash> in the link to the hashes of whichever ones from the PR commits, overcoming the limitation of being able to choose just "from the viewable commits". Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

Github support responded with:

You can use the compare view for that:

https://github.com/rails/rails/compare

You can construct the compare URL manually as well, e.g.

https://github.com/rails/rails/compare/c51aa9f6f2c361e1efc53020028592564318e8a6...35a816a86a74e35b00e1e6d6e55aff01dd40980d

Comment: I feel someone could throw some JS together in a bookmarklet that let you chose any two commits in a PR and it will generate that URL for you...

Comment: This is great and works for Commits without the need to be in a Pull Request

Comment: With `...` (3 dots) in between github shows the commits in the range, meanwhile with `..` (2 dots) it shows the diff. Which is kinda the inverted syntax in `git log`.

Answer (score 10):

GitHub has a built-in way to do this. In the `Files changed` tab, click the "Changes from all commits" dropdown at the top left. Then press and hold down the `shift` key, click your start commit, and then (while still holding down `shift`) click the end commit.